# slide image into the div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to slide 3 images one at the time with ease-out from the left into the red div. When the images are not in the div, they shouldn't be visible

This is the start and end result that I hoped to achieve. The red rectangle is the parent div, and black rectangles are the images I want to slide in.

Any idea how to tackle this problem?

[image]

[image]

```
HTML:

<div id="container">
<img src="black"><img src="black"><img src="black">
</div>

CSS:

#container {
width:380px;
height: 200px;
background-color:red;

}
img{
    width:30px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Have you at least attempted this yourself? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very crude example, but I wanted to knock up a quick demo to point you in the right direction. You're going to need to develop this further, but I know it can be difficult to get started.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ed034mrs/

You don't need Javascript at all, you can do this with CSS animations. The animation is a simple slide from the left and i've staggered the items with a delay.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.outer {
  width: 380px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-1000%);
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s forwards;
}

.inner:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}

.inner:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}

img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You could first set big negative `margin-left` to remove images from window and then use `animate` on margin to slide in images one by one image by using delay and index of each image.

```js
$('img').css('margin-left', '-200vw')

$('img').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i * 500).animate({
   'margin-left': 25
  }, 1000)
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  background: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.red {
  background: #B53535;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="red">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

It would be be much easier if you could just set `justify-content: space-around` but i guess js affects flexbox so this happens [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1576/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt, pretty messy tbh but I hope it gives you some more options to approach.

I positioned the blackboxes outside of the container and set overflow to hidden so they cant be seen outside of the container. Then in CSS when the container is hovered I want the first, second, and third images to move to right.

The second and third images have a transition delay as well. The length of the transition is only 1 second as seen in the img selector, so they will appear one at a time.

```css
.greyBackground {
 background-color: grey;
}

#container {
 margin:auto;
 position: relative;
 width:380px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color:#B53535;
 overflow: hidden;
}

img{
 position: relative;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color: black;
 width:70px;
 height: 90px;
 top:40px;
 right: 220px;
 transition: right 1s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition: right 1s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: right 1s ease-out;
 -o-transition: right 1s ease-out;
}

#container:hover > img:nth-of-type(1) {
 right: -20px;
}

#container:hover > img:nth-of-type(2) {
 right: -80px;;
 transition-delay: 1s;
}

#container:hover > img:nth-of-type(3) {
 right: -140px;
 transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="greyBackground">
 <div id="container">
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
 </div>
</div>
```